# CDF in Python not displaying correctly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cdf

Good morning,

In Python, I have a dictionary (called packet_size_dist) with the following values:

```
34  =>  0.00909909009099
42  =>  0.02299770023
54  =>  0.578742125787
58  =>  0.211278872113
62  =>  0.00529947005299
66  =>  0.031796820318
70  =>  0.0530946905309
74  =>  0.0876912308769
```

Notice that the sum of the values == 1.

I am attempting to generate a CDF, which I successfully do, but it looks wrong and I am wondering if I am going about generating it incorrectly.  The code in question is:

```
sorted_p = sorted(packet_size_dist.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
yvals = np.arange(len(sorted_p))/float(len(sorted_p))
plt.plot(sorted_p, yvals)
plt.show()
```

But the resulting graph looks like this:
[image: CDF of Packet Distribution]

Which doesn't seem to quite match the values in the dictionary.  Any ideas?  I also see a vague green line towards the left of the graph, which I don't know what it is.  For example, the graph is depicting that a packet size of 70 occurs about 78% of the time, when in my dictionary it is represented as occurring 5% of the time.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy makes everything a lot easier. So first you may convert your dictionary to a 2-column numpy array. You can then sort this by its first column. Finally simply calculate the cumulative sum of the second column and plot it against the first.

```
dic = { 34  :  0.00909909009099,
        42  :  0.02299770023,
        54  :  0.578742125787,
        58  :  0.211278872113,
        62  :  0.00529947005299,
        66  :  0.031796820318,
        70  :  0.0530946905309,
        74  :  0.0876912308769 }

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[k,v] for k,v in dic.iteritems()]) # use dic.items() for python3
data = data[data[:,0].argsort()]
cdf = np.cumsum(data[:,1])

plt.plot(data[:,0], cdf)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, doesn't this graph depict that the value "74" occurs about 0.95 of the time?  I thought with a CDF distribution, the sum total needs to == 1.0, which if you sum the dictionary value keys, they do, the graph just doesn't seem to represent that well.  But your code replicates great on my end!

Comment: No, a cumulative density function (CDF) gives you the probability to to find a value lower than some value x. The graph thus tells you that 100% of all values are less or equal 74; or, a better example, the probability to find a value less or equal than 58 is ~82%. If you actually wanted a probability density function (PDF), which gives you the probability of finding a value at or around some value x, you can just plot your data, because it is already normalized.

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you!  No, CDF is what I wanted, I was just switching their meaning in my mind.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Great. So in that case you can choose one of the two answers to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You may additionally upvote both or any of them, in case they've helped you. You might also consider the same for your previous questions in case they are solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a direct answer to your question. However, I thought I should point out that your data arise from a discrete random variable (rather than one that is continuous) and that therefore, representing them with a series of line segments could be somewhat misleading in some contexts. The representation in [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties)  might be overkill. I offer the following simplification.

[image]

An 'x' represents truncation. A dot represents the closed end of a closed-open interval.

Here's the code. I didn't think to use `np.cumsum`!

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

p = [0.00909909009099,0.02299770023,0.578742125787,0.211278872113,0.00529947005299,0.031796820318,0.0530946905309,0.0876912308769]
cumSums = [0] + [sum(p[:i]) for i in range(1,len(p)+1)]
counts = [30,34,42,54,58,62,66,70,74,80]

lines =[[(counts[i],cumSums[i]),(counts[i+1],cumSums[i])] for i in range(-1+len(counts))]

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)

pl.plot([30, 80],[0, 1],'bx')
pl.plot(counts[1:-1], cumSums[1:], 'bo')

ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)

pl.show()
```

This is more like the plot you appear to want. (Corrected, I hope.)

[image]

For which the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
from sys import exit

p = [0.00909909009099,0.02299770023,0.578742125787,0.211278872113,0.00529947005299,0.031796820318,0.0530946905309,0.0876912308769]
cumSums = [sum(p[:i]) for i in range(1,len(p)+1)]
counts = [34,42,54,58,62,66,70,74]

lines = [[(counts[i],cumSums[i]),(counts[i+1],cumSums[i+1])] for i in range(-1+len(p))]

lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)

pl.show()
```

Comment: This solution is pretty strange. You invented some numbers (33 and 90), which are not in the data and render the shown CDF completely wrong.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Expressed with your usual tact. Anyway, not really.

Comment: So you want to say that the curve in the second picture correctly represents the data from the question?